# Python Query 'module' object has no attribute 'test_func'

Tags: python, module, attributes

I am trying to create a new module and method as part of an existing library.

The existing library is called Bly.Pht. I create a new *.py file in this directory called Distance.py. In Distance.py I have the following:

```
class Distance:
    def __init__(self, handle):
        self.handle = handle

    def test_func(t1, t2):
        print "correctly executing"
```

From the Python shell, I do the following:

```
from Bly.Pht import Distance    #this works fine

dist = Distance.test_func(input1, input2)
```

I get the error `'module' object has no attribute 'test_func'`

Can anyone advise as to why this is happening?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are not importing the `Distance` class, you are importing the module that contains the `Distance` class. It can be fixed as:

```
dist = Distance.Distance.test_fund(input1, input2)
```

If you don't plan on including other functionality in `Distance.py`, it's probably a better idea to put the class definition in `Bly/Pht/__init__.py` or in `Bly/Pht.py`, in which case you could import it as you did. (Unlike other languages, Python doesn't encourage each class having its own file).

Answer (score 1):

Python is not Java.  If you created a **file** called `Distance.py` that defines a **class** called `Distance`, you need to `from Bly.Pht.Distance import Distance`.  Or, if there's no good reason to make it a class, just write the method directly in the module.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. So based on this I removed the class "Distance" definition in distance.py and wrote the method in directly. I then invoked the method the same way as originally described and also by dist = test_func(input1, input2). Still throwing an error unfortunately. Any ideas what I'm missing? Many thanks for the reply

Comment: Apologies, please disregard my previous comment - your advice did fix it but I made an error with upper/lower case. thanks again